# Access VBA Set QueryDef.SQL To String From Field Name

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a querydef to change its SQL code by creating a SQL string and then applying it using a field value from dbo_lookups. The dbo_lookups table contains a list of all the SQL strings i.e. strSQLByDepartment etc.

When it gets to the line qrydef.SQL = rst!DataOut1 I get an error 3129 invalid sql statement, this is because it is trying to change the querydefs sql code to say strSQLByDepartment and not the actual SQL code i have already declared, is there anyway i can get it to update to the SQL code using what I have? please help if this makes any sense?

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qrydef = db.QueryDefs("Query1")
Set qrydef2 = db.QueryDefs("Query2")

strSQLByDepartment = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM Table1;"
strSQLByDepartment2 = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM Table2;"

strSQLByP = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM Table3;"
strSQLByP2 = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM Table4;"

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
strLookups = "SELECT dbo_Lookups.Type, dbo_Lookups.DataIn, dbo_Lookups.DataOut1, dbo_Lookups.DataOut2 " & _
"FROM dbo_Lookups " & _
"WHERE (((dbo_Lookups.Type) = 'JobValueTypes')) " & _
"ORDER BY dbo_Lookups.DataIn;"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strLookups)

Do Until rst.EOF = True
    If Me.Report= rst!DataIn Then
        qrydef.SQL = rst!DataOut1
        qrydef2.SQL = rst!DataOut2
    Else
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to test what is being given in `rst!DataOut1` and `rst!DataOut2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Option Explicit and declare your string variables as type string

see [Create Passthough Query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112108)